# 405 error on XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < ctx.fileData.length; i++) {
          formData.append('file', ctx.fileData[i]);
        }

        // now post a new XHR request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/site-manager-gateway/add-content');
        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('all done: ' + xhr.status);
          } else {
            console.log('Something went terribly wrong...');
          }
        };

        xhr.send(formData);
```

I get an error:

```
POST http://dev-site.net/site-manager-gateway/add-content 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

But I'm posting to the same domain.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT, PHP file (site-manager-gateway):

```
public function addContent()
{
    var_dump('a');
    die();
}
```

Comment: You should post the server-side code that receives the requests. 405 means that `POST` is not allowed.

Comment: I don't think the domain has anything to do with the issue. Neither does the JS code you posted. The HTTP code that is returned should really be all the information you need. That URL is simply not allowing you to execute a POST request.

Comment: It;s strange becuase when I take out  formData.append('file', ctx.fileData[i]); It works. There is nothing on the php site other than return 'test';